# Using an id of a table for sql_last_value in logstash?

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, logstash-configuration, elasticsearch-5

I'm having a MySQL statement as such within my `jdbc` plugin in `logstash` input.

```
statement => "SELECT * from TEST where id > :sql_last_value"
```

My table doesn't have any `date` or `datetime` field as such. So I'm trying to update the index, by checking minute by minute using a `scheduler`, whether any new rows have been added to the table.

I should only be able to update the new records, rather than updating the existing value changes from an existing record. So to do this I'm having this kinda of a `logstash` input:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://myhostmachine:3306/mydb" 
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "root"
        jdbc_validate_connection => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "/mypath/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
        jdbc_page_size => "50000"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "SELECT * from mytable where id > :sql_last_value"
        use_column_value => true
        tracking_column => id
        last_run_metadata_path => "/path/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
        clean_run => true
    }
}
```

So whenever I create an index and run this `logstash` file in order to upload the docs, it doesn't get uploaded at all. The docs count shows as zero. I made sure that I deleted the `.logstash_jdbc_last_run` before I ran the `logstash` conf file.

Part of logstash console output:

> [2016-11-02T16:33:00,294][INFO ][logstash.inputs.jdbc     ]
>   (0.002000s) SELECT count(*) AS `count` FROM (SELECT * from TEST where
>   id > '2016-11-02 11:02:00') AS `t1` LIMIT 1

and this keeps on going by checking minute by minute which is correct but then it doesn't get the records. How does it work?

Am I missing something? Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to add `clean_run => true` in your `jdbc` input config? It's not normal that the value used to be compared against the ID field is a date `2016-11-02 11:02:00`

Comment: @Val I tried it with it too, but still the result is the same.

Comment: what `clean_run` does is to delete the `.logstash_jdbc_last_run` file. Maybe try to also specify `tracking_column_type => "numeric"` even though it's the default.

Comment: Maybe also update your question with your latest config...

Comment: @Val what should I specify here `tracking_column_type => `? What do you mean by numeric? You want me to insert something like 0 or 1 or just "numeric" itself? And I've updated the question with the latest conf.

Comment: Same as I described above: `tracking_column_type => "numeric"` It's an undocumented setting

Comment: @Val alright sure, will check on that and get back! Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127199/discussion-between-kulasangar-and-val).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify your logstash configuration like this:

```
jdbc { 
  jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://myhostmachine:3306/mydb" 
  jdbc_user => "root" 
  jdbc_password => "root" 
  jdbc_validate_connection => true 
  jdbc_driver_library => "/mypath/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar" 
  jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" 
  jdbc_paging_enabled => "true" 
  jdbc_page_size => "50000" 
  schedule => "* * * * *" 
  statement => "SELECT * from TEST where id > :sql_last_value" 
  use_column_value => true 
  tracking_column => "id" 
  tracking_column_type => "numeric" 
  clean_run => true 
  last_run_metadata_path => "/mypath/.logstash_jdbc_last_run" 
}
```

The last five settings are important in your case. Also make sure to delete the `.logstash_jdbc_last_run` file even though `clean_run => true` does it.