# Trigger full import in elsatic search using logstash with jdbc

Tags: elasticsearch, jdbc, import, logstash

I use logstash with jdbc plugin to insert data into elastic search. The jdbc plugin reads an last_modified column periodically and insert all the data, which is newer than the last run.
(typical jdbc-logstasah-handling)

But sometimes I need to run an full index from scratch.

How can I trigger that full import (database -> elastic).

My current way is to shutdown logstash, reset the `.logstash_jdbc_last_run` - counter and start logstash again. That doesn't seem very elegant to me.

Is there an different way to trigger the full-import?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add the [`clean_run` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#plugins-inputs-jdbc-clean_run) to your `jdbc` input configuration:

```
input {
  jdbc {
    ...
    clean_run => true
    ...
  }
}
```

Adding that [will ignore the state](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_state) stored in the `.logstash_jdbc_last_run` file.

Comment: But I have to restart logstash or reloade the pipeline-config, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to restart Logstash to take the configuration change into account. Alternatively, you can set `config.reload.automatic: true` in the `logstash.yml` configuration file, which will automatically reload the configuration every 3s (by default)

Comment: okay, restarting is not an elegant solution (it could effect other running jobs). Reloading the config every 3s also looks not ideal. That point goes to solr. :-/

Comment: I think you misunderstand how the automatic reloading works. The configuration is not reloaded every 3 sec, but a check is made every three second (that's also configurable via `config.reload.interval`) to see if the config has changed, in which case, it is reloaded.

Comment: Ah, okay. Important hint. Thank you. 
...but still Solr's point! ;-)

Comment: I understand how Solr can compete with Elasticsearch... but with Logstash 

Comment: I compare Solr with Elastic, but need logstash to index via JDBC (which was the context of the question). I haven't made that clear, sorry.

Comment: I think there's no point in comparing ES with Solr here because that's irrelevant... all you were interested to do was to make sure that sometimes you can reload everything from scratch without taking into account the current loading state. Or am I missing something?

Comment: To be honest, I haven't fully understood how it works. If you set clean_run=>true in logstash, then logstash jdbc input starts and loads everything. But what happens after the initial load? If I keep clean_run, it would start again from beginning. What do I missing? Do I have to update the logstash again and remove or change clean_run again after first initial load?

Comment: @D.Lohrsträter when you've done the initial load (with clean_run => true), the `tracking_column` state will be kept in `.logstash_jdbc_last_run`. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378580/using-an-id-of-a-table-for-sql-last-value-in-logstash/40385238#40385238) for how to proceed next. However, if you restart Logstash for some reason, make sure to set clean_run to false otherwise it will start all over again.